# Xcode header files

Tags: c++, xcode, header

This is a simple question - or maybe not - how do I add external headers to my project (C++ command line tool) in Xcode? How do I also add external dynamic libraries to it? any help greatly appreciated. I am new to xcode.

Max.

Comment: See e.g. step 4 in [this article](http://www.soulstorm-creations.com/PROJECT_SOULSTORM_2_0/programming-articles/installing-portable-libraries-on-os-x.html), Apples [Introduction to Porting UNIX/Linux Applications to Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/intro/intro.html) is also worth a read.

Comment: ...http://www.soulstorm-creations.com/PROJECT%5FSOULSTORM%5F2%5F0/programming-articles/installing-portable-libraries-on-os-x.html is the answer. 1.

Comment: Probably useless due to so much time passed, but here is the new link. https://oramind.com/installing-portable-libraries-on-os-x/ .